# Decrypting the sqlcipher encrypted database on windows

Tags: android, encryption, sqlite, sqlcipher

We are trying to encrypt a database using sqlcipher for an app on an windows system.

Following is the code we are trying to encrypt

```
 SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);
        File databaseFile = getDatabasePath("demo.db");
        databaseFile.mkdirs();
        databaseFile.delete();
        SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, "test123", null);
        database.execSQL("create table t1(a, b)");
        database.execSQL("insert into t1(a, b) values(?, ?)", 
                          new Object[]{"one for the money",
                             "two for the show"});
        database.close();
```

We are successfully able to encrypt the database and when we are trying to decrypt the database we are getting an error saying like `file is encrypted or database not found`.

Can some one please help in decrypting the database.

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**

```
File unencFile = getDatabasePath("Plaintext.db");
                unencFile.delete();

                File databaseFile = getDatabasePath("demo.db");
                databaseFile.mkdirs();
                databaseFile.delete();
                SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, "test123", null);

                database.rawExecSQL(String.format("ATTACH DATABASE '%s' as plaintext KEY '' ", unencFile.getAbsolutePath()));
//              database.rawExecSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '"+"plaintext.db"+"' AS plaintext KEY '';");
                database.rawExecSQL("SELECT sqlcipher_export('plaintext');");
                database.rawExecSQL("DETACH DATABASE plaintext;");
                android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(unencFile, null);
                sqlDB.close();
                database.close();
```

**EDIT 2**

Now I am able to get the decrypted Plaintext.db file. but table name in the db is `android_metadata` rather than `t1`. Both the table size are same but i am not able to see data.

Comment: Well, you are deleting the database file. That will make the database be not found. In fact, the whole `mkdirs()`/`delete()` stuff is rather strange. There is no database from a "windows system" (you can't copy it there on a production device, and even if you had, you deleted it). So you should be creating a new database.

Comment: @CommonsWare that is the sample code we got from sqlcipher site. Can you suggest what changes as to be made ?

Comment: Post your code for decrypting the databse.

Comment: @Devendra added decrypt code

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting the DB file before decrypting. Do changes to your code like below and try

```
  File unencFile = getDatabasePath(PhoneNumbersDatabase.DATABASE_NAME);
  unencFile.delete();
  File databaseFile = getDatabasePath("demo.db");
  SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, "test123", null); 
  if (database.isOpen()) {
   database.rawExecSQL(String.format("ATTACH DATABASE '%s' as plaintext KEY '';",unencFile.getAbsolutePath()));
   database.rawExecSQL("SELECT sqlcipher_export('plaintext');");
   database.rawExecSQL("DETACH DATABASE plaintext;");
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(unencFile, null);
   sqlDB.close();
   database.close();
  }
  databaseFile.delete();
```

Also make changes to your DB encryption code like below -

```
databaseFile.delete();        
databaseFile.mkdirs();
```

Comment: what is PhoneNumbersDatabase.DATABASE_NAME??

Comment: PhoneNumbersDatabase.DATABASE_NAME will be your database file name/path.